# Website layout messing up when the browser is resized

Tags: html, css

As the title suggest, I'm having issues with creating my website.
It's currently at the design stage and I'm having problems upon putting my browser into windowed mode.

Everything sort of re-aranges it self. If you scroll a bit you see some sections falling out of order.

I don't know what I did wrong, but I would very much like to fix this issue.

This is the link to my website as it stands:
http://www.dennis-website.co.nf/index.html

Comment: I assume that your issue is that your Twitter box floats right, so when you make it too small your menu items stick to the right of your page whereas your twitter box hangs over the edge, so when you then scroll right, your menu items stay where they are?

Comment: Unrelated: You have invalid HTML in your lists. `<a href="#"><li>Reviews</li></a>` should be `<li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>`

Comment: @WesleyMurch I didn't know that would be invalid.
I did that to have the background of the list object and the color of the link to change on hover.

Comment: For future reference: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dennis-website.co.nf%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thank you!
What a very cool website.
I will definantly be using this!

Comment: @FrostbiteXIII
Yes that was one issue, but it's solved now due to jerrylow's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no minimum width set to the overall site. Your #container_main has width set at 1002px where as the rest of the site doesn't so the header and menu will collapse to the browser's width. You can quickly solve this by setting

```
#wrapper {
    min-width: 1002px;
}
```

So the overall site has a minimum width.

Comment: Thanks to the other answers, but this is the one that worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to adjust the font size, width of the elements and much more for various screen resolutions.

Example: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I quite understand?
Could you show me an example, or go a bit more in-depth?

Comment: Media Queries are CSS properties with which you can alter the properties of elements in your page based on screen resolutions or device type and more. To see this in reality http://css-tricks.com/ visit this website and resize your browser.

Comment: Oh, now I see.
That's pretty cool, but it isn't really the look I was going for.
What @jerrylow suggested, made it how I wanted it to be.

Thanks anyways, I'll keep Media Queries in mind thought.

Answer (score 1):

`<div id="nav">`

Your CSS must be:

```
#nav

{
width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a responsive design website to overcome this issue. Here is a great book on [**Responsive Design by Ethan Marcotte**](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design). It will cover all topics of how to make responsive grid, responsive images and media queries + this is only 150 pages small free pdf :D